# passing json array to php variable array in same page

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

in this page, I have this button (code below) that if clicked will trigger the script

button code (rolemanage.php) :

```
a href="<?= base_url('admin/roleaccess/') ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#aksesModal" class="badge badge-warning aksesModal" data-id="<?= $r['id_lvl']; ?>" class="badge badge-warning">Akses</a>
```

onclick script (rolemanage.php)

```
$('.aksesModal').on('click', function() {

    const id = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?= base_url('admin/getMenuid'); ?>",
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            var strData = JSON.stringify(data);                
        }
    });
});
```

so the var data success get the array back from admin/getMenuid and the result arrays in console like this :

> (1) […] ​ 0: Object { id: "4", menu: "Barang Habis Pakai" } ​ length:
>   1

then after that I tried to make that object to string using json.stringify in success: function

and the result like this :

> [{"id":"3","menu":"Menu"}]

the question is : when I tried call strData in this page (rolemanage.php) using

> var_dump(json_decode($_POST['strData']));

it shows undefined index strData.

how to get the strData value then ?

Comment: Where have you defined `$id_user` and `$lv_user`?

Comment: You didn't even declare `$id_user` and `$lv_user`

Comment: on a side note: don't ever store passwords as plain-text. it's basically the biggest no-go of handling passwords. use `password_hash()` to create a secure hash of it and `password_verify()` to check if a password is valid.

Comment: check [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: What is output of `$cetak`?

Comment: @KinshukLahiri i declare $id_user & $lv_user based on session value thats why i ask why getting error.

Comment: @GustiAldi You are assigning those values to session without declaring them.

Comment: @AHJeebon its 0 or more than 1 (depend on how much user with the same value)

Comment: `DECLARING` is different from `ASSIGNING`. You are `assigning` `$id_user` and `$lv_user` to `SESSION` without even `declaring` them.

Comment: Variables are assigned with the = operator, with the variable on the left-hand side and the expression to be evaluated on the right.

Comment: @VishalParkash its work, but when i tried to echo $id_user or $lv_user it didnt show anything, why ?

Comment: try this:
$id_user = '1';
$lv_user = '2';
$_SESSION['log_usr'] = $id_user;
$_SESSION['sts_usr'] = $lv_user;

Now try echo $id_user or $lv_user..
Still Empty ??

Comment: @KinshukLahiri  and irvin why you are asking variable is not declared?
Do you have any idea of function extract();  search it. [see](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Comment: @VishalParkash i try echo 2 of them and it says 12, and thats mean my declare with value of session didnt work ?

Comment: @AHJeebon You can see the output of that extract and beside that if it was there then the variable was declared and no error should be there. It is clearly saying that variable is not declared and hence told him to do so :)

Comment: Ok, Let us know where and what values has been assigned by you for the variables $id_user and $lv_user? You are getting confused somewhere i guess..

Comment: @VishalParkash okay, I tried to create 1 login form for 2 level authorithy (user & admin), so i tried with this code and i add session for getting value of id_user & lv_user on my table, then if i get that 2 value i can use if-else to pointed user to user page and admin to admin page. as far i know my logic didnt work on this problem :')

Comment: Try this code after you fetch records from database -----
//Assuming that the table column are id_user and lv_user
   $id_user = $cetak["lv_user"];
   $lv_user = $cetak["lv_user"];
   
            $_SESSION['log_usr'] = $id_user;
            $_SESSION['sts_usr'] = $lv_user;
Then try to echo the session or those variables $id_user and $lv_user

Comment: @KinshukLahiri I tried to change my question, can you help me with my problem sir ?